# Asynchronous File copy in java

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-io, read-write, java.nio.file

I want to know how we can move a file to a different location asynchronously,
basically one of my program is keep on appending data to a temporary file and another is checking its size on exceeding the predefined size of the temporary file it should be copied to a permanent directory and the previous program should keep create a new temporary file and continue writing, in between the data copied should not lost.
I tried to do the same with the following code but some of the data are either misplaced or lost.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class FileSizeMonitor {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FileSizeMonitor.class.getName());
    private static final String tempDirectory = "c:\\my-temp-dir";
    private static final String tempFileName = tempDirectory + "\\" + "my-temp-file.txt";

    void FileMonitor() {
        File file = new File(tempFileName);
        double bytes = 0;
        if (file.exists()) {
            bytes = file.length();
            if (bytes > 2458.0001) {
                int length;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                try {
                    InputStream inStream = null;
                    OutputStream outStream = null;

                    String source = tempFileName;
                    String target = "C:\\Users\\data";

                    File sourceFile = new File(source);
                    String fileName = sourceFile.getName();
                    File targetFile = new File(target + fileName);

                    inStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);

                    log.debug("File size exceded the predefined limit,moving the file data to  C:\\Users\\data");

                    while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }

                    inStream.close();
                    outStream.close();

                    sourceFile.delete();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What I've done is start a new temporary file when the current temporary file is full, like what Eclipse does with its log file.  You can either have several names for temporary files, or stop the logging long enough to rename the current temporary file before creating the new temporary file.